# SQL Select Top 3 into separate columns

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a very simple query that selects the top 3 codes from a table and I would like to either store them in a temp table as separate column values or fetch into a separate declared fields.

Top 3 query:

```
 select  top 3 code
 from table1 t1 (NOLOCK)
 join table2 t2 (NOLOCK) on t1.codeid = t2.codeid
 where t2.recordid = '123456789'
 and t1.codetype = '987654'
```

Results:

```
  code  
  1111 
  2222
  3333
```

Preferred output:

```
  code1     code 2     code3 
  1111      2222       3333
```

I also could go for something else like:

```
 Declare @code1 as varchar(4)
 Declare @code2 as varchar(4)
 Declare @code3 as varchar(4)
 DECLARE RULE_CURSOR CURSOR STATIC FOR
 {select statement here}

 OPEN RULE_CURSOR
    FETCH NEXT FROM RULE_CURSOR into @code1, @code2, @code3
```

The Declare and Fetch into is actually my preferred method if someone could help me out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out from a separate post I had inquired about previously:

```
 DECLARE RULE_CURSOR CURSOR STATIC FOR
      WITH    cte
      AS ( SELECT   top 3 code,  ROW_NUMBER() over( order by code) rn
           from  Table1 T1 (NOLOCK)
           join table2 t2 (NOLOCK) on t1.codeid = t2.codeid
           where t2.recordid = '123456789'
           and t1.codetype = '987654')
 SELECT [1] AS Code1 ,
        [2] AS Code2 ,
        [3] AS Code3
 FROM cte PIVOT( MAX(code) FOR rn IN ( [1], [2], [3] ) ) a
        Open RULE_CURSOR
     FETCH NEXT FROM RULE_CURSOR into @code1, @code2, @code3
```